# How to disable the "screen locking disabled" notification in gnome 3.38?

Tags: gnome, lightdm, gdm, display-manager

This message pops up after every login, this started happening when I removed the desktop icons gnome extension - DING https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/ (I'm using lightDM and I want to keep it, is there any other way besides downloading GDM?)
the message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwDcx.png
I don't need screen locking, I just want to disable that notification, is there any way to do it besides installing GDM? i really like lightDM and I don't want to uninstall it

Comment: update: i saw that this is a bug, and it happens to some people, it's in the file js/ui/main.js, but i can't find it on my system